# Increase the space in / from other mount points

Tags: centos

Currently system is running low in sapce in `/`.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        30G   28G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  202M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           379M   52K  379M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda         50G   28G   19G  60% /home/**/***
tmpfs           379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb         20G   45M   19G   1% /data
```

And have some space in other place.

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  50G  0 disk /home/**/***
vda     253:0    0  30G  0 disk 
├─vda1  253:1    0  30G  0 part /
└─vda15 253:15   0   1M  0 part
```

How can I add some space in `/` from `/data`.

Comment: Check where the most space is used (`du -hs`). Since sdb is nearly empty, it might be beneficial to mount it somewhere else, or to partition it and mount one part in `/data` and one part somewhere else.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those are physical partitions you can't. The only thing you might be able to do is to create a symbolic link from /home/empty to /var/log/something where first directory is an empty directory in /home filesystem and second directory is a directory that causes you problems for / (filling your FS).

Also as far as I can see you are using different types of disks (vda is virtio disk and sda,sdb are scsi disks)

There might be also a possibility if you have access to virtualization layer and you are able to increase the vda disk. If that applies you can check this link: https://geekpeek.net/resize-filesystem-fdisk-resize2fs/ . I forgot to mention that since you are trying to do the changes for a running operating system you MUST take all actions while booting from a LIVE CD, otherwise it will be impossible.